# How to convert and configure igraph object to JSON

Tags: r, json, igraph, netjson

I have used the `d3r` package to convert an `igraph` object to JSON format like so:

```
# create small world network    
net <- sample_smallworld(size = 8, dim = 1, nei = 1, p = 0.33) 

# convert to json with directional edges   
data_json <- d3_igraph(as.directed(net))
```

This gives me the following output:

```
> data_json
{"nodes":[{"id":"0"},{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"},{"id":"4"},{"id":"5"},{"id":"6"},{"id":"7"}],"links":[{"source":"0","target":"1"},{"source":"1","target":"6"},{"source":"2","target":"3"},{"source":"3","target":"4"},{"source":"0","target":"4"},{"source":"3","target":"5"},{"source":"6","target":"7"},{"source":"0","target":"7"},{"source":"1","target":"0"},{"source":"6","target":"1"},{"source":"3","target":"2"},{"source":"4","target":"3"},{"source":"4","target":"0"},{"source":"5","target":"3"},{"source":"7","target":"6"},{"source":"7","target":"0"}],"attributes":{"name":"Watts-Strogatz random graph","dim":1,"size":8,"nei":1,"p":0.33,"loops":false,"multiple":false}}
```

This is nearly what I want, but I need to configure two things:

1. I want node IDs to start at 1, not 0.
2. I want to remove the quotes around the node IDs *in the links* (the quotes are fine as they are in the nodes element), so that each link is written like this `{"source": 1, "target": 2}`, instead of `{"source": "1", "target": "2"}`

I could of course just do this manually for a small network like this, but that's tedious and not scalable for large networks. Is there better way I can this is `R`?

Comment: 1. Can't you just add 1 to each ID after making the JSON?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd like to do, but how?

Comment: a possibility might be to edit the node IDs directly with igraph. Maybe with set_vertex_attr("id", value = 1:8)

Comment: I tried `net <- net %>% set_vertex_attr("id", value = c(1:8))` but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy enough to convert the json into an R list and make the necessary changes to the data before writing back to json. Here's a function that should do the trick for the output of `d3_igraph`, using tools from the `jsonlite` package:

```
fix_d3_json <- function(json)
{
  dj <- jsonlite::fromJSON(data_json)
  dj$nodes$id   <- as.numeric(dj$nodes$id) + 1
  dj$links[[1]] <- as.numeric(dj$links[[1]]) + 1
  dj$links[[2]] <- as.numeric(dj$links[[2]]) + 1
  jsonlite::toJSON(dj)
}
```

So now you can do:

```
library(igraph)
library(d3r)

# create small world network    
net <- sample_smallworld(size = 8, dim = 1, nei = 1, p = 0.33) 

# convert to json with directional edges   
data_json <- d3_igraph(as.directed(net))

# Fix json
data_json <- fix_d3_json(data_json)

data_json
#> {"nodes":[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5},{"id":6},{"id":7},
#> {"id":8}],"links":[{"source":1,"target":6},{"source":1,"target":2},
#> {"source":2,"target":3},{"source":3,"target":4},{"source":2,"target":6},
#> {"source":3,"target":6},{"source":6,"target":7},{"source":1,"target":7},
#> {"source":6,"target":1},{"source":2,"target":1},{"source":3,"target":2},
#> {"source":4,"target":3},{"source":6,"target":2},{"source":6,"target":3},
#> {"source":7,"target":6},{"source":7,"target":1}],"attributes":
#> {"name":["Watts-Strogatz random graph"],"dim":[1],"size":[8],"nei":[1],
#> "p":[0.33],"loops":[false],"multiple":[false]}}
```

Comment: Great answer. Although your output looks exactly right, I had to make one small change in the function to have this work for me: `fix_d3_json <- function(json)
{
  dj <- jsonlite::fromJSON(data_json)
  dj$nodes$id   <- as.numeric(dj$nodes$id) + 1
  dj$links[[1]] <- as.numeric(dj$links[[1]]) + 1
  dj$links[[2]] <- as.numeric(dj$links[[2]]) + 1
  jsonlite::toJSON(dj)
}` ... Otherwise the links would reference node IDs 0-7, despite the ID attributes in the nodes element ranging from 1-8.